# how to disable a DataTables/TableTools button

Tags: datatables, tabletools

I'm using DataTable 1.10 and TableTools 2.2.1.

Given the following snipped I would like to disable/enable the edit-button.

```js
var myTable = $("#myTable ").DataTable({
tableTools : {
    "aButtons" : [ {
        "sExtends" : "text",
        "sButtonText" : "Edit",
        "fnClick" : function(nButton, oConfig, oFlash) {
            /* some stuff */    
        }
    }]
  }
})
```

Is there a possibility to do this at runtime?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a good question! Seems that the `fnClick` in

```
dataTable.tabletools().fnSettings().buttonSet[id].fnClick
```

only is a reference to the event stored elsewhere, not accessible (changing `fnClick` on the API has no effect). However, you can use the predefined class `DTTT_disabled` and check for that in your `fnClick`-handler :

```js
var dataTable = $("#example").DataTable({
   sDom: 'TC',
   oTableTools : {
       aButtons : [{
            sExtends : "text",
            sButtonText : "Edit",
            fnClick :  function(nButton, oConfig, oFlash) {
                 if ($(nButton).hasClass('DTTT_disabled')) return;
                 alert('edit button clicked');
            }
       }]  
  }
});
```

example with a checkbox enabling or disabling the button :

```js
$("#enable").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.DTTT_button_text').removeClass('DTTT_disabled');
    } else {
        $('.DTTT_button_text').addClass('DTTT_disabled');
    }
});
```

see demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/ev2N2/**